# New comparison of Eclipse and NetBeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide

Since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408929/what-is-the-best-free-ide-for-java-programming) staled a year and a half ago, has there been some significant development on these projects that would warrant a re-evaluation of the answers? The majority opinion seemed to be that NetBeans was better for JAVA GUI development or JavaScript, otherwise Eclipse was equal or better.

Answer (score -1):

You should check out Aptana Studio. It's Eclipse based and version 3.0 was released in April.